# Let $G$ be an abelian group and a subgroup $H\le G$ . Is $G$ isomorphic to $H\times (G/H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group and a subgroup $H\le G$ . Is $G$  isomorphic to $H\times (G/H)$. G can be finite or infinite.  Notice this is a bit like Fisrt Homomorphsm Theorem, I tried to prove it like the way done in this theorem , but failed. Is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in general, no. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $H= \langle 2 \rangle$. Then $H \times G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: what if G is infinite?

Comment: @LOIS Still no. Just take a similar example (cyclic group).