# Abelian group G is isomorphic to the direct product of $G/H$ and $H$, $G/H$ is cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Complete question is :

> Let $H\le G$, G is an abelian group, define $\bar{G} = G/H$. Prove or give a counterexample:
>
> (1) If $\bar{G}$ is a finite cyclic group, then $G\cong\bar{G} \times H$
>
> (2) If $\bar{G}$ is a infinite cyclic group, then $G\cong\bar{G} \times H$

My thoughts:

(1) has a counterexample, seen as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023704/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-and-a-subgroup-h-le-g-is-g-isomorphic-to-h-ti)

As for (2), I think it's right, because I can take $H_0 =  \langle a \rangle, a\notin H$, which is guaranteed by $\bar{G}$ is infinite cyclic group. Then it's clear that $H_0\cong \bar{G}$ and $G\cong H_0\times H$

Is that right?

Thank you.

Comment: You should keep looking for counterexamples for (2). In particular, try cases where $H \simeq G$ but $H \neq G$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thank you Morgan, I'll try harder :)